# Executing the foreach block at the same time for all items?

Tags: c#, foreach, xamarin.forms

I have this foreach loop that changes the Image's Source for four images (in a Xamarin Forms app):

```
int i = 0;
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), () =>
            {
                i ++;
                foreach (var img in imgs)
                {
                    img.Source = $"radial{i}.png";
                }
                if (i == 5)
                    i = 0;
                return true;
            });
```

but the result is that the four images are not changing simultaneously and the animation is not smooth. Here the grid is divided to four quarters, each quarter has its own image view:

[image]

When I use `FromSeconds(1)` instead of `FromMilliseconds(200)`, the animation become more smooth

These are the images I use, I rotate them when I want to draw a complete circle:

[image]

Comment: And you don't want to wait 1 second?

Comment: Please update your post to show each of the images so we can see what the animation is _supposed_ to look like.

Comment: I updated it with the images

Comment: Why have you split the image into 4 quarters? Why not just use a single image?

Comment: I'm doing this already now, but the I need to do it by splitting images also.

Comment: You want a solution where four bitmaps are drawn **simultaneously**. Without knowing much about the underlying tech I don't believe that is possible at all. The rendering is essentially single thread so each image will always be drawn one after the other. In computer games and other similar applications you use a back buffer to composite the new image and then blit it to the screen to solve this problem but that seems like overkill for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using System.Collections.Concurrent and call your loop using

```
Parallel.ForEach(imgs, img => {
    img.Source = $"radial{i}.png";
});
```

However judging by what you want to achieve, I'd rather create the animation programmatically with the SkiaSharp drawing plugin.